# (ba)sh - Determine (based on machine name) whether a computer is on the local network

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Working on a shell script that takes a machine name as an argument and then determines if the host is on the local network (same network as the machine that ran the script).

How can I get the IP address from the machine name? Once I get that I should be able to compare that IP with the local one to see if they're on the same subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nslookup` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup), `dig` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) or `host` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/host) command-line utilities.

For example, here is the result of running `host` for getting A-records for stackoverflow.com from DNS server:

```
$ host -tA stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 69.59.197.21
```

Comment: `dig +short` is probably the best for scripts. `host` has different output in different versions (been there, done that, wounded self in foot).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `local network`? subnet or (windows) domain or within LAN?

You may also have a look at [`traceroute`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) utility.